# sending back api data to vue in express returns empty object

Tags: express, vue.js

I'm trying to send some data back from my express app using the following in my app.js this data comes from a 3rd party api and I want to send it back to my front end application. I am able to see the content in my express api but it doesn't seem to deliver a result to my front end?? anyone have any ideas as to why I'm getting log below in the console.

I suspect it has to do with some async or timeout issue with the express app but I haven't been able to fix the issue myself.

```
function getFish(){
        axios.get('https://www.fishwatch.gov/api/species')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
               return response

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
}


app.get('/getFish', async(req,res) =>{
    let fish = await getFish()
    res.json({fishes: fish})
})
```

when I try to log the data in my app, I only get an empty object

```
{}
```

here is my vue code to log the value's returned by my express api.

```
 created:function(){
     this.fetchFish()
   },

  methods: {

      fetchFish(){
         fetch('http://localhost:3000/getFish')
          .then((response) => {
             return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `axios` promise in your server's `getFish` function or the `/getFish` route won't be `await`ing anything:

```js
function getFish(){
    // New `return` statement
    return axios.get('https://www.fishwatch.gov/api/species')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: yes that worked for me, I can see the data now inside my getFish route  :) I have never used axios but I couldn't use fetch on the backend so thanks for helping me out